# Why do we write Synchronized(ClassName.class)

Tags: java, design-patterns, thread-safety, synchronized-block

I have a question in singleton pattern.
In singleton pattern we write

```
synchronized(ClassName.class){

     // other code goes here

}
```

What is the purpose of writing `ClassName.class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a member method (non-static) you have two choices of which monitor (lock) to use: "***this***" and "***my class's single static lock***".

If your purpose is to coordinate a lock on the object instance, use "***this***":

```
...
synchronized (this) {
  // do critical code
}
```

or

```
public synchronized void doSomething() {
 ...
}
```

However, if you are trying to have safe operations including either:

- static methods
- static members of your class

Then it is critical to grab a class-wide-lock.  There are 2 ways to synchronize on the static lock:

```
...
synchornized(ClassName.class) {
   // do class wide critical code
}
```

or

```
public static synchronized void doSomeStaticThing() {
   ...
}
```

**VERY IMPORTANTLY**, the following 2 methods **DO NOT** coordinate on the same lock:

```
public synchronized void doMemberSomething() {
   ...
}
```

and

```
public static synchronized void doStaticSomething() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each class (for example `Foo`) has a corresponding, unique instance of `java.lang.Class<Foo>`. `Foo.class` is a literal of type `Class<Foo>` that allows getting a reference to this unique instance. And using

```
synchronized(Foo.class)
```

allows synchronizing on this object.

Answer (score 0):

The object that you pass into the synchronized block is known as a monitor.  Since the object that represents the class `className.class` is guaranteed to only exist once in the JVM it means that only one thread can enter that synchronized block.

It is used within the singleton pattern to ensure that a single instance exists in the JVM.