# Difference between synchronized

Tags: java, object, synchronization

Is the `this` and `Example.this` the same object?

E.g. Is the call `this` and `Example.class` inside the `synchronized` the same object?

```
class Example {
    public Example() {
        synchronized(this) {
            // some code
        }
    }
}


class Example {
    public Example() {
        synchronized(Example.class) {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obivously not. The first is an object, the second the whole class.

Comment: `Example.class` is the example class. `this` is an specific instance of `Example`. Not the same.

Comment: no they are not the same. `this` returns the current instance, whereas `Example.class` returns the instance of the class of `Example`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946728/why-do-we-write-synchronizedclassname-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Synchronizing on `this` is *instance-level* locking, meaning that the critical section cannot be re-entered with same object.

Synchronizing on `Example.class` is *class-level* locking, meaning that no other instance of the class, including `this`, can enter that critical section.

As you can see, *class-level* locking is, in a sense, more drastic.

Answer (score 3):

No, `this` use current object as monitor, but `Example.class` use `Example.class` as monitor.

Answer (score 1):

No, `this` is an instance of `Example` while `Example.class` is an instance of `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

This will synchronize access to the locked class instead of the this/current object. Use whichever you find easier and more effective.